# Перевод терминов "my logins" и "login"

Tags: поддержка, локализация, термины

Варианты:

- «мои логины», «логин»
- «мои имена пользователей», «имя пользователя»
- «мои учётные данные», «учётная запись»
- «данные для входа»

Прежде чем сделать выбор, подумайте как это повлияет на перевод account, network profile, credentials, username, которые также используются в интерфейсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

Голосуем за "my logins", "login" = «мои учётные данные», «учётная запись»

---

*Остальные варианты.*

- "my logins", "login" = «мои логины», «логин»
- "my logins", "login" = «мои имена пользователей», «имя пользователя»
- "данные для входа". Если будет список из: мыло, g+, facebook и т.д. его надо как-то озаглавить получше чем логины...
- "my logins", "login" = «мои учетные записи», «вход»