# Совместный перевод сайта сообществом

Tags: поддержка, faq, локализация, термины, правила

Оглавление:

### [1. Как принять участие в переводе сайта?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1137/)

### [2. Руководство для переводчиков.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1136/)

### [3. Глоссарий.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1135/)

### [4. Заметки о типографике и пунктуации русского языка.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1150/)

Comment: Там остался минимум.

Comment: Мне кажется, разделение на отдельные _вопросы_ может привести к путанице. Если я вас правильно понял, вы предлагаете сделать что-то [аналогичное](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/173/)?

Comment: Это отличная идея!

Comment: сделано. Раздел «Как принять участие в переводе сайта?» я существенно дополнил. Поскольку активный перевод через Transifex уже вроде бы закончился, перенес этот вариант участия в конец ответа. Предлагаю вам принять ответ с этим разделом, чтобы он был виден в первую очередь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Здорово! Спасибо!

Comment: примете первый пункт? Он самый актуальный, остальные два найдут по оглавлению.

Comment: Готово. Хотя, мне кажется, это не сыграет большого значения. Сейчас, информация прекрастно структурирована.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ух ты, а как у вас получилось сделать общим **вопрос**? это же, вроде, доступно только модераторам.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: владею особой магией. См. также http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/983/ и http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1160/ =)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Как принять участие в переводе сайта?

### Как сообщить об обнаруженной ошибке в переводе?

Очень просто. Задайте [новый вопрос с метками [дефект] и [локализация]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

### Можно ли переводить разделы справки и популярные вопросы с Меты других сайтов?

Да, но не те, которые касаются правил сообщества. StackOverflow на русском языке не наследует неявным образом правила StackOverflow на английском или любого иного сайта. Вы можете инициировать дискуссию относительно правил, задав [новый вопрос с метками [обсуждение] и [правила]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0).

Любые публикации о том, как лучше задавать вопросы и отвечать на них, пользоваться сайтом и участвовать в жизни сообщества стоят того, чтобы их перевести (или написать с чистого листа).

Если вы хотите перевести или улучшить справочные материалы сайта, прочитайте вопрос «https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/91/181472».

### [Стоит ли переводить вопросы и ответы с англоязычного SO?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/70/181472)

Кратко: да, определённо стоит. Подробный ответ вы можете найти по вышеприведенной ссылке.

### Как переводить, используя систему Traducir

StackOverflow на русском использует Traducir для перевода интерфейса. Любой зарегистрированный участник может предложить перевод новой строки или исправление существующего перевода. Для этого необходимо:

1. Перейти по адресу [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win/)
2. Войти в систему с помощью вашей учетной записи StackExchange.
3. Найти нужную строку. Для этого введите ее фрагмент в поле "Source Regex" (для поиска по англоязычной строке) или "Translation Regex" (для поиска по переводу). При необходимости поиска по шаблону можно использовать регулярные выражения.
4. Щелкнуть по строке в появившихся результатах поиска.
5. В открывшемся окне ввести новый вариант перевода в поле "New Suggestion". Обратите внимание, что он должен содержать все переменные исходной строки (начинаются с символа "$"), если они в ней есть. Можно использовать кнопку "Copy as suggestion", чтобы скопировать строку с переменными в поле.
6. Нажать кнопку "Send new suggestion". Ваше предложение будет проверено модератором или редактором и утверждено, если оно правильно. Утвержденный перевод появится на сайте после выхода новой версии (через несколько дней).

Через систему Traducir **не переводится** следующее:

- Страницы справки. Они доступны для редактирования только администрации и, в определенных случаях, модераторам. Задайте вопрос на мете, если перевод в справке ошибочен или отсутствует.
- Интерфейс чата. Чат не локализован в принципе, все строки в нем не переведены.
- Строки, для которых заданы [переопределения](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/11655/240512). В основном, это строки, касающиеся юридических вопросов. Любые изменения этих строк через Traducir будут автоматически перезаписаны движком сайта.

Подробнее о Traducir: [Мы переходим на Traducir.win для перевода интерфейса сайта!](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8256/).

[Список участников с правом утверждения переводов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10114/240512)

Будем рады видеть ваши предложения. Создадим наш Островок Знаний вместе!

Comment: Ввожу в поле "Source Regex" цитатку из чата "The last message was posted 6 days ago". Результат: "No results (sad trombone)"... Или для чата переводы не делаются?

Comment: @ВарламЕрофеич Да, чат не локализован в принципе, на уровне движка. Ни одной строки из чата в Traducir нет.

Comment: Смотрю на https://ru.traducir.win/ и "умиляюсь"...  
— Почему же сам Traducir не переведён? Ведь он же "ru.traducir.win"

Answer (score 14):

### Заметки о типографике и пунктуации русского языка

Типографика и пунктуация, принятая в русском языке, в основном сходна с английской, но имеется ряд небольших отличий.

### Кавычки

Подробно освещается [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/493/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8). Вкратце: «ёлочки (при вложенных „лапках“)».

### Тире

Почти везде, где тире уместно в английском языке, оно уместно и в русском.
Преобладающий тип тире в английской пунктуации — среднее тире «–» (`&ndash;` U+2013).
В большинстве случаев его следует, при переводе на русский, заменять длинным «—» (`&mdash;` U+2014).
В английском языке может как отбиваться пробелами, так и не отбиваться,
смотря по контексту.
В русском отбивка пробелами применяется чаще, а именно — между двумя словами — в любом случае.
Существует практика делать пробел, предшествующий тире, неразрывным (напр. `&nbsp;` U+00A0), дабы избежать появления строк, начинающихся с тире, при неудачном переносе строки.

Примеры:
Русский             Английский

> модель «хищник — жертва»  predator–prey model

При расположении тире между двумя невербальными единицами (числами, символами, и т.п.) пробел, как правило, не ставится в обоих языках.
Также существуют разногласия, следует ли в этом случае в русском языке 
использовать длинное тире (2—3) или среднее (2–3).
Оба варианта могут считаться правильными.

Примеры:
Русский     Английский

> 2—3 часа     2–3 hours
>   2–3 часа

Ввод:

**Windows**: используем [Alt-код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4). Включить Num Lock, набирать на цифровой клавиатуре

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0151</kbd> = — (длинное тире)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0150</kbd> = – (среднее тире)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0160</kbd> = « » (неразрывный пробел)

**X:**

- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> = — (длинное тире)
- <kbd>Compose key</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> = – (среднее тире)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> = — (длинное тире)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> = – (среднее тире)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> = « » (неразрывный пробел)

**OS X:**

- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> = — (длинное тире)
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> = – (среднее тире)
- <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> = « » (неразрывный пробел)

### Дефис

Есть одна ситуация, когда в русском языке дефис употребляется, где в английском его не ставят.

Примеры:
Русский     Английский

> альфа-канал   alpha channel
>   стоп-код     stop code
>       но:
>   4-вектор     4-vector
>   *n*-мерный    *n*-dimensional

Как правило, как в русском так и в английском языках для дефиса используется ASCII-символ «-» (U+002D).

Существуют и другие коды дефиса.

Дефис **никогда** не отбивается пробелами.
Есть редкая ситуация, когда правильно пишется «- »:

> цис- и транс-изомеры.

Но, в большинстве использований в Интернете, «- » возникает в силу невежества, как популярная замена символу двоеточия «:».

### Запятые

При длинном перечислении в английском языке запятые как правило ставятся везде между записями.

В русском запятая не ставится перед союзом «и».

Примеры:
     Русский          Английский

> страх, неопределённость и сомнение  fear, uncertainty, and doubt

### Десятичные числа

Символ дробной части — «.» в английском и «,» в русском.
Разделитель тысяч — «,» в английском и неразрывный пробел (возможно, уменьшенной ширины, типа « » U+202F) в русском.

Примеры:
Русский  Английский

> 1 024   1,024
>      0,125   0.125

Ввод:

**X:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> = узкий неразрывный пробел

### Знак процента

Какой-то-там стандарт рекомендует ставить, в русском языке, неразрывный пробел между числом процентов и «%».
Как во французском языке, в общем.
На практике мало кто так делает.

Comment: Как вы думаете, возможно стоит разместить данную публикацию отдельным вопросом с меткой [meta-tag:faq]?

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky: В принципе, оно к написанию любых текстов имеет отношение, не только к переводу сайта. Посмотрю с утра, что люди скажут, и (возможно) выложу отдельной темой.

Answer (score 8):

## Глоссарий

#### Правила наполнения глоссария

Этот глоссарий наполняется на основе открытого обсуждения на Мете.

- Если требуемого термина нет в нижеприведенном списке, то он, возможно, находится в стадии обсуждения. [Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с текущим обсуждением терминов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B).
- Если термин ранее не обсуждался, то вы можете инициировать обсуждение нового термина. Обязательно следуйте инструкции из вопроса «https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/494/181472». [Опубликуйте новый вопрос, используя эту ссылку.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=discussion%20%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B&title=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%20___?)

#### Утвержденные переводы терминов

1. account — учётная запись
2. [audit](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/459/) — проверка.
3. [badge](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/469/) — знак.
4. [bounty](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/485/) — приз (вознаграждение),
   bounty started — начало конкурса,
   bounty ended — окончание конкурса (с награждением).
5. [content](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/825/) — содержимое
6. [election](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/471/) — голосование.
7. [email](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/491/) — почта, письмо.
8. [excerpt](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/455/) — краткое описание.
9. [FAQ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/451/) — FAQ.
10. [flag](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/467/) — тревога,
    to flag — отметить тревогой,
    useful flag — полезная тревога,
    not helpful — не несет пользы,
    flagged message — сообщение, отмеченное «тревогой».
11. [grace period](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3295/) — свежая правка.
12. [graduation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1089/) — аттестация.
13. [Help center](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/463/) — Справка.
14. [login, my logins](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/445/) — учётная запись, мои учётные данные («ё»!).
15. [meta](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/481/) — Мета (с большой буквы и склоняется: на Мету).
16. [nominate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/471/) — выдвинуть кандидата,
    nominees — кандидаты,
    nomination — выдвижение кандидатов.
17. [phase](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/471/) — этап (голосования).
18. [posts](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/483/) — сообщения.
19. [recent answers/questions](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/449/) — последние вопросы/ответы.
20. [reputation](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/457/) — репутация, баллы репутации.
21. [score](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/487/) — рейтинг.
22. [tag wiki](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/473/) — описание метки (меток).
23. [(tag) wiki excerpt](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/455/) — краткое описание (метки).
24. try again — попробуйте еще раз.
25. [users](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1054/) — участники/пользователи.
26. [website](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/479/) — сайт.
27. [wiki](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/477/) — общие вопросы/ответы,
    [converted to wiki](/questions/477/) — сделан общим.
28. [DMCA Takedown](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12611/339283) — Уведомление о нарушении DMCA.
29. [Copyright policy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12616/339283) — Политика авторских прав.

Для участников, которые принимали участие в первоначальном переводе интерфейса и имеют учетную запись в Transifex, доступен также [глоссарий в Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/glossary/ru/)

Answer (score 8):

## Руководство для переводчиков

### Зачем нужен коллективный перевод?

1. Перевод — отчасти творческое занятие. В сообществе мы используем много непрямых переводов с английского, например, «flag» → «тревога», в то время как большинство переводит это слово просто как «флаг». Чем больше творческих людей, обладающих литературным языком, примет участие, тем более «русскоязычным» будет перевод, а как результат — форумом будет приятнее пользоваться.
2. Коллективное редактирование поможет исключить ошибки, которые один человек добавил бы в дополнение к уже существующим.
3. Скорость такого перевода намного быстрее.

### Общие рекомендации по переводу

Работая над переводом, мы стараемся использовать как можно более литературный язык, по возможности избегать заимствованных слов. По нашему мнению, такой перевод позволяет быстрее разобраться в сложном функционале сайта и предоставляет лучший опыт пользователю.

#### Перевод терминов

Для того, чтобы обсудить перевод нового термина, используйте инструкцию в вопросе [Каким образом принимать решения о выборе правильного варианта перевода?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/494/).

Если для часто употребляемого термина существует утвержденный вариант перевода, то следует использовать его. Список утвержденных терминов [приведен в соседнем ответе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1135/).

Вам также может быть доступен более подробный [глоссарий в Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/glossary/ru/).

#### Замечания

- В подавляющем большинстве случаев переводчики опускали слово «пожалуйста».
- Переводчики часто злоупотребляют переводом слова «this» («этот»). В 90% случаев слово «этот» излишне, в оставшихся 10%, по моему опыту, «this» лучше переводить как «данный».
- Переводя сообщения об ошибках, подобные «An error occurred during submission», следует указывать причину ошибки в начале сообщения. То есть, *верно*: «При отправке возникла ошибка», *неверно*: «Возникла ошибка при отправке».
- В большинстве случаев в переводе строк необходимо использовать «кавычки-ёлочки», при вложенных кавычках — „лапки“. Подробнее: [Как следует писать кавычки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/493/).

#### Строки для единственного и множественного числа в Transifex

- Для определения множественного числа используется поле комментарий (находится под полем перевода). Если строка имеет несколько версий, в комментарии будет указан `DEVELOPER NOTE`: one/few/many.

  - one : 1, 21, 31 ...
  - few : 2-4, 22-24, 32-34 ...
  - many: 5-20, 25-30, 35-40 ...

#### Внутренняя система меток Transifex

- `context-issue` — отмечаются строки, контекст использования которых непонятен.
- `tag-issue` — отмечаются строки относящиеся к меткам, перевод которых следует проверить.
- `review-issue` — отмечаются строки, в которые были внесены изменения во время выставления второй галки.
- `adapt-me` — для больших строк, которые должны быть адаптированы (например, письма-благодарности).

#### Специальная разметка в Transifex

В Transifex есть «магические» строки, которые прогоняются через систему перевода повторно и преобразуются потом в реальные. Одной из таких строк является `[help]`, которую, как оказалось, переводить не стоит, так как затем она превратится в `справочном центре` + ссылка.

Подробнее: [Complete list of help center magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links)