# Мы участники или пользователи?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

В некоторых местах, мы – [участники](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261653?qt=%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA). В других, мы – [пользователи](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261623?qt=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB).
<sub>(ссылки на Transifex для удобства переводчиков)</sub>

Зачем используются оба термина? Можно ли изменить перевод, чтобы везде были либо участники, либо пользователи?

[На странице участников/пользователей:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users)

[image: ссылка "участники" панель "вопросы-метки-участники..."]

[В профиле участника/пользователя:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA)

[image: видимо, этот пользователь...]

Comment: Отличный вопрос. Хоть вы и не носитель языка, а обращаете внимание на такие важные мелочи.

Comment: В смысле голосования — там выбора нет. В голосовании можно принять участие, но нельзя воспользоваться.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не понял, почему выбора нет?

Comment: нельзя сказать «пользователи голосования». Даже «голосующие пользователи» звучит ужасно. Поэтому остается единственный выбор — «участники голосования».

Comment: @PeterOlson, голосование — это процесс. можно быть участником процесса, но нельзя быть его пользователем. но можно воспользоваться **результатами** процесса.

Answer (score 16):

Следует везде употреблять **участник**.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Это ставит акцент на том, что мы активны по отношению к сайту, мы создаем его содержимое и несем за него ответственность.

Comment: Не могу голосовать за свои ответы, но я лично за это.

Comment: «Участники» («участники сообщества») звучит лучше, но иногда, в целях избежать тавтологию я использую «пользователи».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: [в словаре для переводчиков явно указано когда-какой термин нужно использовать](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068/23044). Не могу найти на Мете страницу c ХэшКода: "перевод - Общие понятия и термины"

Comment: Если человек только читает сайт (пришёл с гугла, прочитал ответ, побежал дальше - то есть человек, который использует сайт -- пользователь), можно ли его участником назвать, если он не голосует, не отвечает на вопросы, не комментирует, не задаёт вопросы и тд?

Comment: @jfs: не эту ли страницу вы ищете? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: наверно это самый близкий вариант, который возможен, но на оригинальной странице [(см. ссылку в моём ответе)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1068/23044) был одобренный перевод для users.

Comment: @jfs Отличное замечание! Старую Мету закрыли, дабы не вводить никого в заблуждение.

Comment: @jfs: обновили список терминов. На оригинальной странице не было ссылки на обсуждение перевода, так что здесь я дал ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Небольшое уточнение:

Термин «пользователь» нужно оставить в тех случаях, когда

1. Идет речь о юридических соглашениях между Stack Exchange и участником. В смысле этих соглашений мы четко определены как «пользователи» сайта, этот термин закреплен в документах.
2. «Пользователь» означает не человека, участвующего в сообществе, а его учетную запись. Насколько я понимаю, все эти строки относятся к инструментам модератора (я выбрал их специально, они мне очень понравились)

   > - (515) Удаление пользователя $id$
   > - (518) Не удается удалить пользователя
   > - (519) Уничтожение пользователя $id$

   Строки, которые видны малому числу пользователей, например только модераторам, стоит вообще оставить в покое. Существенного улучшения для большой массы пользователей их правки не принесут. А еще этих строк много, очень много.

Comment: в данном случае (пункт 2) следует использовать термин "учётная запись". Про юридичекие соглашения (пункт 1) -- что является источником?

Comment: @jfs: про учетную запись, пожалуй, соглашусь. Стоит когда-нибудь исправить. Но это всё равно задача не первого приоритета.

Comment: Лично мне ближе всего именно этот ответ. Но я бы добавил свои 5 коп.: если речь идет о сообществе единомышленников (community), а SO - это бесспорно сообщество, то тогда к сообществу применимо понятие *участник*. Например, я живу жизнью community, я принимаю в ней участие, я - _участник сообщества_. А пользователь - это тот, кто _пользуется_; кто изредко заходит позадавать вопросы и не ставит своей целью внести вклад в развитие ресурса/сообщества.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown: не представляю, как в общем случае разделить тех и других.

Comment: Может даже сложиться такая семантическая пара: участники сообщества отвечают на вопросы пользователей :-)

Comment: Да это и не нужно на самом деле. Самые правильные решения - простые решения. И тут надо сильно не мудрить и идти по пути упрощений, имхо. Русский язык беспримерно богат и чрезвычайно сложен. И обращать внимание на _легкие неточности_ всегда будем только ты, я, да еще пара перфекционистов :) Поэтому я бы оставил все как есть.

Comment: Если «пользователь» означает всегда «учётную запись», то почему бы и не писать прямо так? (515) _Удаление учётной записи $id$_, (518) _Не удается удалить учётную запись_, (519) _Уничтожение учётной записи $id$_?

Comment: @VladD получается "пользователь" вообще не нужен, а остаются только "участник" и "учётная запись"?

Comment: @alexolut: Ну мне кажется, да. Два термина для одного понятия создают путаницу. Но замечание Ника, конечно, имеет смысл, так что в юридически обязывающих местах нужно использовать то, что хотят юристы.

Comment: @VladD есть ещё замечание (ответ jfs) про то что "пользователь" - это read-only. Правда тут получается некоторая дилемма, когда участник зарегистрировался, но ещё ничего не писал, он вроде как должен считаться пользователем :)

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, мне это разделение кажется искусственным. Написал один комментарий или проголосовал за вопрос — уже участник? А если комментарий был удалён, то снова пользователь?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите в [glossary на transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/glossary/ru/). Там указаные рекомендации для переводчиков (чтобы одинаковые термины одинаково переводились в разных местах). Вот комментарий к переводу слова users:

> Участник  --совершает активные действия: голосует, задаёт вопросы,
>   пишет ответы, комментирует; пользователь - читает 
>   [https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/research/3048/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B](https://web.archive.org/web/20150401033259/https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/research/3048/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B)

То есть следует оставить оба термина и использовать где уместно.

Comment: Если там есть такой хороший глоссарий, то глоссарий на Мете как минимум неполный.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: утвержденный список терминов отслеживался по hashcode.ru ссылке из ответа. Словарь на transifex, просто для удобства, потому что он интегрирован с интерфейсом -- все спорные термины в нём имеют ссылку на утверждённый список с hashcode.ru. Сейчас, как показывает пример данного обсуждения, каждый термин можно на Мете в виде отдельного вопроса публиковать, если есть сомнения с переводом.

Answer (score 1):

В кратких строках (там, где место ограничено версткой или смыслом)

> **Участник**
>
> - Видимо, этот участник предпочел окутать себя завесой тайны.
> - Необходимо еще $numVotes$ голосов других участников, чтобы закрыть вопрос.

В полновесных текстах следует предпочитать полный вариант, но без дублирования.

> **Участник сообщества**
>
> - Мы недавно обратили внимание, что большое количество голосов на вашей учётной записи отдано или получено от определенных **участников сообщества**. Мы поощряем **участников** отдавать положительные голоса полезным постам, исходя из качества *постов*, не учитывая заслуги их авторов.

Comment: "поощрять отдавать" - ужасная калька. "поощрять передачу голосов"

Comment: @Igor голоса не передаются, речь о процессе голосования. Есть выражение "отдать голос за...". Если звучит плохо, давайте подумаем, как улучшить.

Comment: Кстати, тут и "посты" неверно употребляется. Должны быть "сообщения" .

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, не вник до конца в смысл фразы. "Мы поощряем голосование за полезные сообщения" или "мы призываем голосовать за полезные сообщения".

Comment: @Igor хороший вариант. Тут на Мете еще пара десятков вопросов есть, где вы можете что-нибудь улучшить.

Comment: @Igor и это всячески приветствуется. )

Answer (score 0):

Ничего делать не надо.

Answer (score -5):

Следует везде употреблять **пользователь**.

Comment: Пользователь (юзер) — это даже немного ругательное слово в среде энтузиастов IT.

Comment: Кстати, «юзер» напомнил мне о великолепном произведении, которое я хочу вам порекомендовать: [Андрей Щербаков. 9600 бод и все-все-все...](http://www.lib.ru/ANEKDOTY/9600.txt)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Очень смешно. Где вы это раскопали?

Comment: @VerNick в моём детстве (90е и начало 2000х), когда было противопоставление хакеров и юзеров. Мы конечно все хотели быть хакерами. Но сидели на винде и программировали только в школе на Паскале и VB.

Comment: @VerNick а, или вы про ссылку на произведение? Ну, оно тоже откуда-то из детства или юности. Там ещё продолжение есть.