# Текст статистики по голосам требует исправления

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, мобильная-версия

В мобильной версии сайта текст статистики по голосам (активность профиля, режим "сводка" и мотаем в самый низ экрана) требует исправления. 
В текущем варианте выглядит так:

> Из всего числа отданных голосов: 91 голосов «за», 19 голосов «против». Пользователь alexolut голосовал за вопросы 48 раз и за ответы 62 раз.

На transifex это всё задается [единственной строкой](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267024?key=e3ab9db57bdc11952b4569001f948e7e):

Оригинальный текст:

> Of the votes cast, *$up$* were up-votes and *$down$* were down-votes. $DisplayName$ voted on questions *$q$* times and *$a$* times on answers.

Перевод:

> Из всего числа отданных голосов: *$up$* голосов «за», *$down$* голосов «против». Пользователь $DisplayName$ голосовал за вопросы *$q$* раз и за ответы *$a$* раз.

Поэтому самый простой способ - привести эту фразу к виду, не требующему разных окончаний числительных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Перевод](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267024?key=e3ab9db57bdc11952b4569001f948e7e) 10 октября 2016 года принял следующий вид:

> Из всего числа отданных голосов: *$up$* «за», *$down$* «против». Участник $DisplayName$ проголосовал в вопросах: *$q$*, в ответах: *$a$*.

Но он мне не очень нравится. Имеет смысл добавить для этой строки [множественные формы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3921/176217) для улучшения качества перевода.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю следующий вариант перевода (с заменой "пользователя" на "участника", согласно [обсуждению](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1054/%D0%9C%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8)):

> Из всего числа отданных голосов: $up$ «за», $down$ «против». 
>   Участник $DisplayName$ уделил голосов вопросам: $q$, ответам $a$.

Comment: Отправил запрос на добавление множистеннвх форм для количества вопросов и ответов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky тут ещё [вопрос](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3862/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85) в том, стоит ли упоминать ник вообще.

Comment: Если в исходной строке есть переменные, мы не можем их опускать в переводе. Такая строка просто не загрузится в движок.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky безобразие! На самом деле в данном случае есть смысл спросить у "старших братьев" зачем тут вообще упоминание ника. Было бы интересно услышать ответ.

Comment: Вряд ли на этот вопрос есть ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky если ответа нет, то надо предложить выпилить упоминание ника из данной строки, и все дела.