# Список строк transifex, требующих множественных форм

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Некоторые строки, необходимые для локализации сайта, должны иметь различные формы для разного количества сущностей, используемых совместно с этими строками. Но на текущий момент для таких строк существует только одна форма:

- [flags remaining today](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264367?key=1be11d78a7a56a10248abdeec20dd4f9)
- [flags remaining today, UTC](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264373?key=8ce7a73759f37512a29f4ab55596fea0)
- [the $ItemsMax$ most recently active $htmltags$ questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265275?key=53b66bf427e6734e2a95c79d1799c743) (пока что можно адаптировать под ItemsMax=30)
- [the $ItemsMax$ highest voted $htmltags$ questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265272?key=214cd326cfc5dfc2e2d09c791f1ec72a) (пока что можно адаптировать под ItemsMax=30)
- [the $ItemsMax$ newest $htmltags$ questions](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265274?key=48d7c595963728196af6856bbd7a39ea) (пока что можно адаптировать под ItemsMax=30)
- [$EligibleVotersCount$ voters were eligible, $VisitedSiteDuringElectionCount$ visited the site during the election, $ViewedElectionCount$ visited the election page, and $VotedCount$ voted](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262810?key=f438fe1eddc4ab276b964d42b8614059)
- [posts](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263358?key=18958e30bdca0cfac8256824e570a89b)
- [$historyType$ by](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262860?q=historytype%20by) (группа строк, содержащих "historyType" и "by". Нужны множественные формы в зависимости от кол-ва участников)
- [Browse other questions tagged $QuestionTagLinks$ or ask your own question](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265332?key=8483753d2e45a256a40f46a08c7d4cf9).
- [questions tagged](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267639?q=questions%20tagged) (общее множество строк, содержащих "questions tagged". Это порядка 50 строк сейчас. Нужны множественные формы с учётом кол-ва меток.)
- [$RevisionCount$ revs, $AuthorCount$ users $TopUserPercentage$%$br$$TopUserName$](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262818?key=89a602ef4b125d4a5ff7d8fb3de18a88) (по двум переменным: revs и users)
- [$count$ user accounts have been **merged** into this user.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266465?key=938016e158b6f4a83925c6dfdde07d37)
- [the $ItemsMax$ featured questions ending soonest](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264799?key=1e9f819f66118742cd50ab3c8f995b57) (пока что можно адаптировать под ItemsMax=30)
- [the $ItemsMax$ featured $htmltags$ questions ending soonest](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265280?key=913de19357936da563574bb363411a51) (пока что можно адаптировать под ItemsMax=30)
- [This user has been **contacted** by a moderator $count$ times.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266456?key=55a005f5201ceab994250fe64e697d57)
- [need review](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40265556?key=c9187d8b8d769a79c9333b846aecb8d4)
- [Of the votes cast, $up$ were up-votes and $down$ were down-votes. $DisplayName$ voted on questions $q$ times and $a$ times on answers.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267024?key=e3ab9db57bdc11952b4569001f948e7e) (4 переменные предполагают 3^4 = 81 строку, т.о. Данную фразу следует разбить хотя бы на 2 при добавлении множественных форм)

Если вы нашли строку, которая должна быть в этом списке, пожалуйста, внесите её путём редактирования этого сообщения. Если для строки уже появились множественные формы и перевод по ним выполнен - строку можно удалить из списка. При удалении строки из списка, следует добавить в описание правки ссылку на новую переведенную строку с множественными формами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На данный момент было исправлено все за исключением:

- «posts» – это имя выборки.
- «questions tagged» – пожалуйста, укажите, каким именно строкам следует добавить множественную форму. В указанной в вопросе выборке у большинства строк есть множественная форма, а те строки, которые ее не имеют, по большей массе являются именами сортировок, заголовками RSS-выборок и т. д.
- «Browse other questions tagged $QuestionTagLinks$ or ask your own question.» – исправили сам перевод.

Comment: Что значит "имя выборки"?

Comment: @alexolut Например, «новые вопросы» – это имя выборки/сортировки.

Comment: Понятно. Надо всё-таки что-то сделать с 81 строкой. И под что-то я имею ввиду вовсе не перевод. Т.к. это издевательство.

Comment: Для "questions tagged" нужны множественные формы по кол-ву **меток**, не вопросов!

Comment: Ещё хотелось бы понять, почему нельзя добавить множественные формы для "Browse other questions...". Решение через альтернативный перевод - менее гибкое.

Comment: Старое "need review" почему-то осталось в transifex. Ссылки на другие строки (где добавили множественные формы) дают пустой результат.

Comment: @alexolut Проверил, на данный момент ссылки на строки работают.

Comment: Открываю первую же ссылку из вопроса: [flags remaining today](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40264367?key=1be11d78a7a56a10248abdeec20dd4f9). Вижу: `Нет результатов поиска`. У Вас иначе?