# Активность по голосам

Tags: предложение, локализация, профиль-участника

Во вкладке активности профиля секция "Голоса" сейчас выглядит так:

[image: Голоса]

Считаю, что было бы правильным привести слова "вопрос" и "ответ" к нужной форме, учитывающей кол-во.

Для этого, судя по всему, нужно [добавить множественные формы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3921/176217) для ["question"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40261813?key=5494af1f14a8c19939968c3e9e2d4f79).