# Некорректная форма количества найденных вопросов

Tags: дефект, локализация, метки, поиск

При выполнении поиска по меткам сообщение о количестве найденных вопросов не согласовано по числу («по метк**е**», даже если меток несколько):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала показалось, что написано "вопрос_ов".

Comment: @alexolut, должно быть, кёрнинг у Google Chrome на Windows 7 несколько сбоит.

Comment: Есть ещё мысль, что вместо "по" должно быть "с". Но это надо по всему сайту согласовывать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу необходимости множественных чисел есть [соответствующий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3921/176217). Нечто подобное там озвучено в пункте:

> Browse other questions tagged $QuestionTagLinks$ or ask your own question.

Правда, чтобы лучше понимать о чём там речь, надо иметь возможность доступа к  проекту "*Stack Overflow на русском*" на transifex.

Чтобы привести в порядок все строки, похожие на упомянутые в Вашем вопросе, нужно добавить множественные формы для целой [группы строк](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267639?q=questions%20tagged) (поиск по "questions tagged"). Это порядка 50 строк, т.е. довольно много. Добавил эту информация в связанный вопрос.