# Устаревший(е) ответ(ы) - один или несколько?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

В [конкурсном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/602532/176217) увидел такую формулировку из числа стандартных:

> [image: устарело]

В оригинальной строке transifex фраза звучит так:

> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

Т.е. видимо контекст не предполагает возможность получить кол-во вопросов, ну а если бы предполагал, то строку просто следует внести в [список строк, требующих множественных форм](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3921/176217) для последующего фикса.

В любом случае, имеющая запись с вариантами в скобках мне кажется кривоватой. Если уж всё учитывать, она должна бы и вовсе выглядеть более монстральной, типа:

> Имеющий(е)ся ответ(ы) устарел(и), необходимо проверить его(их) с учётом недавних изменений.

Но это совсем через край. Предлагаю обсудить варианты более цивильной версии перевода, исходя из варианта, что множественных форм (т.е. разных строк) тут не будет.

Comment: Может, просто использовать множественное число? Меньше фич — меньше поддержки, меньше багов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно и так. Но, с одной стороны, хотелось бы соответствовать оригинальному варианту. С другой - хорошо бы выяснить, почему в оригинале решили использовать вариант со скобками, а не сразу множественное число. Может и на enSO строка нуждается в изменении на самом деле.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Поддерживаю. Оставить лишь множественную форму.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky готово. Можно дёргать transifex и закрывать вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выбрали множественную форму в качестве основной:

> [Имеющиеся ответы устарели, необходимо проверить их с учётом недавних изменений.](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262909?key=fdda7fb1e2b945085f48f2a8d9c63083)