# Перевод новых достижений Favorite Answer и Stellar Answer

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

С добавлением нового функционала для работы с заметками добавились и новые достижения, связанные с данным функционалом.

В частности появились достижения:

- Favorite Answer
- Stellar Answer

и у них отсутствует перевод названий и описаний условий получения:

см: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Добавил переводы:**

> Favorite Answer
> Избранный ответ

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18266

---

> Stellar Answer
> Звездный ответ

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18081

---

> Answer saved by 100 users
> Ответ добавили в закладки 100 пользователей

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18268

---

> Answer saved by 25 users
> Ответ добавили в закладки 25 пользователей

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18186

---

> Question saved by 25 users
> Вопрос добавили в закладки 25 пользователей

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18297

---

> Question saved by 100 users
> Вопрос добавили в закладки 100 пользователей

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18329

<strike>**Требуется подтверждение для публикации.**</strike>

**UPDATE:** подтверждено. ожидаем публикации.

Comment: [стараемся писать «участники», а не «пользователи»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1054/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо. Принял.

Comment: Я в основном и так стараюсь так писать, но тут по всей видимости увлекся дословным переводом