# Нужен перевод для подсказки при наведении на вкладку "участие"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, мета, участие

На [ruMSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com) в разделе [участники](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users) есть вкладка [участие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=participation). Если навести мышкой на эту вкладку, то покажется подсказка, где написано ([в Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17987)):

> Users most active on this site (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits)

Предлагаю переводы:

- > Участники, наиболее активные на этом сайте (суммарное количество постов, голосов, комментариев и правок)
- > Участники, наиболее активные на этом сайте (суммарное количество вопросов, голосов, комментариев и правок)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мы тут [участники](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1054/176217). И строки лучше сразу в traducir предлагать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А разве не лучше для истории тут тоже иметь вопрос об этом? Обычно про переводы пишут тут на Мете. Да и у меня 2 варианта, не знаю какой лучше будет, потому лучше пусть проголосуют или кто-то более опытный решит что должно быть, например вы :)

Comment: Вопрос тут. Предложение в традусир. Если нет предпочтительного варианта, то просто прямую ссылку на строку. Ибо бывает, что и строки нет - и надо писать на MSE, чтобы добавили.

Comment: post = сообщение

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Так оформлять вопрос? Если нет, то измените мой вопрос и я буду знать как в следующий раз оформлять, когда есть сомнения

Comment: @αλεχολυτ сообщение в русском, очень широкий смысл несёт. Комментарии же то же сообщения, а тут именно посты/вопросы. Вопрос тоже несёт широкий смысл но у нас тут уже принято говорить "задай вопрос" , подразумевая что нужно сделать новый пост

Comment: Применимо к SE исторически переводим post именно как "сообщение". Комментарий - это комментарий. Тут мы никогда его не называем сообщением.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Но мы тут и не говорим никогда "напиши сообщение", мы говорим "задай вопрос", не? Или post - это не обязательно заданный вопрос?

Comment: post (сообщение) = это или вопрос, или ответ.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А, если ответ - post, тогда хорошо, согласен :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Нужен статус завершено

Comment: [и тревога](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12634/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Я читал это, но тут уже общались с тобой, потому была твоя метка, потому решил через сообщение будет быстрее, чем через тревоги :)

Comment: хахах вот и я попался на скриншоте :D

Answer (score 2):

Участники, наиболее активные на этом сайте (суммарное количество постов, голосов, комментариев и правок)

Comment: заменил посты на сообщения и утвердил. Будет в новых сборках.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Кстати, не знаю насколько это важно тут, но я пропустил точку в конце предложения. В оригинале он есть, а в переводе нет. Лично мне нравится без точки :)

Comment: С точками там и в оригинальных строках бардак. Нет никакой системы

Comment: Попробуем [разобраться с точками](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388978/339911) на этих кнопках.

Answer (score -1):

Участники, наиболее активные на этом сайте (суммарное количество вопросов, голосов, комментариев и правок)