# Перевод термина "graduation"

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, термины, аттестация

Для обозначения выхода сайта сети Stack Exchange из стадии публичной беты используется термин "graduation". Каким образом его следует перевести?

**В ответах предлагаю вам переводить эти фразы вместе с предлагаемыми вариантами, чтобы можно было оценить, как термин «чувствует себя» в контексте.** ([Источник](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).)

1. Название и краткое описание метки Меты.

   [здесь-название-метки](/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8)

   > Вопросы, связанные с graduation, как и зачем сделать graduate и что это принесет сообществу.
2. Как существительное "graduation":

   > The graduation date of a site will depend heavily on having enough users with sufficient reputation to properly lead and govern the site.
3. И как глагол "to graduate":

   > If you want your site to graduate from beta sooner rather than later, encourage your fellow community members to vote early and often!

   (насколько я понял, "early and often" относится к "encourage").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мои ассоциации термина связанны с получением аттестата зрелости. В разных культурах этот процесс совершенно разный: от получения аттестата в университете до ритуальных процессов. Предлагаю достаточно консервативную версию.

#### graduation - аттестация

1. [аттестация](/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

   > Вопросы, связанные с аттестацией, как и зачем проходить аттестацию зрелости сообщества и что это принесет сообществу.
2. > The graduation date of a site will depend heavily on having enough users with sufficient reputation to properly lead and govern the site.
   >
   > Финальная дата аттестации сайта сильно зависит от количества участников, которые готовы и могут достойно управлять сообществом.
3. > If you want your site to graduate from beta sooner rather than later, encourage your fellow community members to vote early and often!
   >
   > Если вы хотите быстрее пройти аттестацию вашего сайта, призывайте других участников сообщества принимать участие в голосовании.

Comment: Принял ваш вариант, метку создал. Что вы думаете о таком формате обсуждения перевода термина, когда предлагается перевести контекст?

Comment: Отличный формат! Возможно, только не стоило удалять альтернативные варианты. Они отличные. Мне кажется, многим будет интересно следить за всем процессом перевода, а не только за итоговым вариантом.

Comment: хм, пожалуй верно. Восстановил альтернативы.

Answer (score 0):

#### «Выпуск [сайта [из (бета-стадии|беты)]]»

**Глагол: «выпуститься [из (бета-стадии|беты)]»**

В англоязычных текстах используется вариант значения этого слова, обозначающий выпуск из учебного заведения.

В русском языке всё даже немного лучше. У нас одним словом обозначается создание законченного результата и в учебном (студент), и в производственном (продукт) смысле. Мы все понемногу учимся и совместными усилиями создаем базу знаний, один большой продукт.

Отдельно нужно обсудить, использовать ли вариант «быть выпущенным».

1. [выпуск-сайта](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0), [выпуск-из-беты](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b)

   > Вопросы, связанные с выпуском StackOverflow на русском: критерии, цели, задачи и координация действий сообщества. Выпуск — это результат завершения бета–стадии.
2. > The graduation date of a site will depend heavily on having enough users with sufficient reputation to properly lead and govern the site.
   >
   > Дата выпуска сайта из бета-стадии будет в существенной степени зависеть от наличия достаточного количества пользователей с репутацией, позволяющей должным образом руководить сайтом и направлять его в нужное русло.
3. > If you want your site to graduate from beta sooner rather than later, encourage your fellow community members to vote early and often!
   >
   > Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш сайт скорее выпустился, то сразу и как можно чаще призывайте других участников сообщества принимать участие в голосовании.

(насколько я понял, "early and often" относится к "encourage").

Comment: Я надеюсь, формат заголовка всем понятен?

Answer (score 0):

#### «Выход [сайта] из (бета–стадии|беты)»

**Глагол: «Выйти из (бета–стадии|беты)»**

Поскольку само по себе «выход» или «выйти» не несет должного смысла, всегда используем с «бетой». «Бета–стадия» для более официальных случаев, вроде текстов справки, а просто «бета» – для обычного общения.

1. [выход-из-беты](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b)

   > Вопросы, связанные с выходом StackOverflow на русском из бета-стадии: критерии, цели, задачи и координация действий сообщества.
2. > The graduation date of a site will depend heavily on having enough users with sufficient reputation to properly lead and govern the site.
   >
   > Дата выхода сайта из бета-стадии будет в существенной степени зависеть от наличия достаточного количества пользователей с репутацией, позволяющей должным образом руководить сайтом и направлять его в нужное русло.
3. > If you want your site to graduate from beta sooner rather than later, encourage your fellow community members to vote early and often!
   >
   > Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш сайт скорее вышел из бета–стадии, то сразу и как можно чаще призывайте других участников сообщества принимать участие в голосовании.