# Показывать некоторые свои принятые ответы первыми

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, голосование

Сейчас принятый ответ гарантированно отображается первым, только если он не принадлежит автору вопроса. Хотелось бы, чтобы в некоторых случаях принятый собственный ответ также закреплялся на первом месте, а именно:

- Вопрос изначально задаётся с отметкой "Ответить на собственный вопрос"
- Вопрос и/или ответ являются общими

PS: Навеяно [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454683/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) - хотелось бы всегда видеть русскоязычные источники первыми.

Comment: может быть, порядок изменится, если у принятого ответа сделать дату последнего редактирования поновее, чем у непринятого? ещё, возможно, тут (дополнительно) влияет несущественная разница в количестве голосов.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, порядок зависит от даты, по крайней мере, при некоторых сортировках. Но вообще, условия помещения принятого ответа я видел где-то в правилах - он должен быть чужим...

Answer (score 4):

Всё так и задумано. У автора вопроса изначально неравные права в возможностях выделения правильного ответа, поэтому, если принимать свой ответ, то он отобразится первым, только если у него больше всего голосов. Считается, что если автора не удовлетворил ни один из чужих ответов, то сообщество в праве перевесить выбор авторского ответа своими голосами. Ну и чтобы авторы не читерили и не пытались словить больше плюсов за счёт выставления своего ответа напоказ.

Не нравится — голосуйте.

Что касается литературы, то если сообщество считает английские ресурсы более полезными, то имеет на это право.

Comment: В целом я согласен с этой логикой, но я привёл 2 ситуации, когда было бы логично сделать по-другому. А что касается литературы - там в английский ответ сегодня ещё одну ссылку добавили и он поднялся. Сортировка у меня выставлена Текущие. А голосов как раз у русских больше. Т. е., вероятно, сортировка идёт именно по свежести - какой позже изменили, тот и наверху.

Comment: @Qwertiy По умолчанию сортировка по голосам. Если вы изменили сортировку, то она соответствует вашим предпочтениям.

Comment: Сортировка "Текущие" и на [этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460946/178988) вопросе видно, что при такой сортировке принятый попрос первых, хотя у второго больше голосов.

Answer (score 1):

В списках литературы и в любых других вопросах, где ответы – это части одного большого ответа, а не конкурирующие отдельные решения, можно использовать оглавление.

Посмотрите, как это реализовано в этом вопросе: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/181472)

Сделал такое же оглавление [в вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/181472), посмотрите. Кстати, поправил там названия сайтов сети согласно рекомендации: [Русский, русскоязычный и Stack Overflow на русском языке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1630/181472)