# Русский, русскоязычный и Stack Overflow на русском языке

Tags: поддержка, faq, правила

Зачастую, многие участники упоминают сообщества Stack Overflow по-разному. Например, в случае с русскоязычным Stack Overflow встречаются три следующих варианта:

- Русский Stack Overflow.
- Русскоязычный Stack Overflow.
- Stack Overflow на русском.

Есть ли различия или это одно и то же? Если есть, то какой вариант правильный?

Answer (score 9):

Различие есть, большое. Сравним два названия:

- Stack Overflow *на английском*

и

- *Английский* Stack Overflow

В первом случае, название говорит о том, что в сообществе общение идет на английском языке. Второй вариант говорит о том, что сообщество каким-то образом относится к Британии (английский чай – чай из Англии). Как вы можете видеть, правильным является именно первый вариант.

Для сообществ, где название языка, на котором идет общение в сообществе совпадает с названием страны, в которой проживает подавляющее большенство носителей языка, эта ошибка в названии не видна так явно, но ошибкой не перестает быть.

Вторым доводом в пользу названия сообщества «Stack Overflow на **название языка**» является понимание того, как образуются сами сообщества: нас всех объединяет не гражданство и не место проживания, мы вместе создаем базу знаний на каком-то языке!

*Пожалуйста, для избежания недопониманий, используйте названия правильно*!

- Stack Overflow на английском;
- Stack Overflow на русском;
- Stack Overflow на португальском;
- Stack Overflow на японском;

Comment: Так что, «Русскоязычный Stack Overflow» - неправильно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну я, например, не русскоязычный, но всё равно использую Stack Overflow на русском)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Русский Stack Overflow не верно на 146%. Русскоязычный, как мне кажется, намного лучше, но тоже не отражает всей идеи объединения сообщества вокруг создания знаний на русском языке.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky про "русский SO" я ничего не говорил.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Да, конечно. Я лишь выразил картину «в общем».

Comment: Да, с позиции правил русского языка текущее название верно. Но с позиции юзабилити оно слишком длинное. И чтобы его написать, нужно дважды переключать раскладку.

Comment: @Oceinic Полностью согласен, что проблема переключения раскладки есть. Есть ли у вас конкретные предложения, как от этого отойти?