# Для знака "делегат" считаются только вопросы или ответы, или и то, и то?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, термины, знаки

Для знака [делегат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/68/convention) необходимо:

> 10 сообщений на Мете с рейтингом 2 балла.

Считаются только вопросы или ответы, или и то, и то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, «сообщения» — это термин для обозначения совокупности вопросов и ответов. Комментарии не считаются.

Соответствующий англоязычный термин — "posts".

На всякий случай, список принятых переводов вынесен в отдельный ответ: [Коллективный перевод сайта сообществом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1032/181472) / [Глоссарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1135/181472)