# Описание знака «Учитель»

Tags: дефект, знаки

[Гласит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher):

> Ответить на вопрос с рейтингом минимум 1 балл.

По мне так в описании даже не амфиболия, а вполне определённо утверждается, что 1 балл должен быть у **вопроса**, а не ответа.

Произвольно выбрал двух участников, недавно получивших знак: [пример 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/494661/199934), [пример 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487835/199934). У вопросов по нулям плюсов и минусов, тогда как отвечающим поставили плюс. Из чего исходит, что знак присуждается за **ответ**. Т. к. знаки на Stack Overflow, похоже, [не отзываются обратно](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258768/5951529), возможны 2 варианта:

1. Сколько бы не минусовали ответ, участник получает знак «Учитель», если его ответу хоть кто-нибудь в любой момент времени поставит плюс.
2. Или же ответ должен сначала получить плюс, а потом пусть его минусуют.

я не нашёл рабочих примеров с минусами, почему не могу определённо заявить, какой из вариантов корректный. Но в любом случае, полагаю, описание знака требует изменения.

Comment: Балл должен быть именно у вопроса. Т. е. смог ответить на хороший вопрос и получил за это знак. Я когда-то удивился, когда получил такой первый раз)

Comment: @Qwertiy, на примеры взгляните. У вопросов в них на момент написания данного комментария по 0 плюсов и минусов.

Comment: Но голос можно и отменить...

Comment: @Qwertiy, [из свежего](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher): [**пример 3**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520911/199934), [**пример 4**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517841/199934). Да, возможно произошли отмены голосов, но я не думаю, что ими пользуются настолько часто.

Comment: Хм.. Может и так... А что тогда за вопрос было?

Comment: Английское описание [гласит](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher): `Answer a question with score of 1 or more`. Предлагаю третье толкование: знак даётся в момент, когда рейтинг ответа оказывается единицей. Т.е. при последовательности оценок `против`-`за`-`за` знак будет выдан после второго `за`, а не после первого.

Comment: [Еще одно](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258) английское описание: `Receive a score of one on an answer`.

Comment: На основе английских версий и глоссария предлагаю в своём ответе новую версию толкования и перевода.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, тогда с учётом Ваших условий примерно следующее должно быть: `Иметь в любой момент времени рейтинг за ответ 1 или более`. Ну и да, знак в одной линейке с «хорошим», «отличным» и «лучшим» ответом должен находиться.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Думаю всё же, что этот знак не про крутость ответа, как хороший-отличный-лучший, а про первый опыт признанного другими ответа. Поэтому он и отдельно стоит. И поэтому рубеж рейтинга надо преодолеть не навсегда, а однажды, хотя бы на секунду.

Answer (score 7):

**Отчёт**

Вместе с Сашей Черных провели эксперимент. Спасибо за помощь [Дмитрию Симушеву](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182771/).

Выбрали из вопросов Саши тот, в котором меньше тегов, и дали ответ от имени тестового [пользователя-новичка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/210017/):

> **Не голосуйте "за" или "против" этого ответа!**
>
> Пожалуйста, не трогайте кнопки голосования рядом с этим ответом. Это
>   тест. С его помощью [Gleb
>   Kemarsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208926/) и [Саша
>   Черных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/) проверяют работу
>   сайта. Подробности - [в
>   Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3012/) и [в
>   чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39518/).
>
> Спасибо за понимание!

Тут же проголосовали - сначала "против", потом "за". Рейтинг получился нулевым. Подождали час, чтобы системе успела обновиться, но знак так и не появился. Зато другой пользователь получил награду уже через полчаса после своего ответа. Поэтому решили, что вторая гипотеза опровергнута.

Теперь понадобился ещё один голос "за". Попросили помощи на общем чате, и  откликнулся Дмитрий. Рейтинг стал единицей, и через пару минут был вручен знак "Учителя". Поэтому считаем доказанной третью гипотезу:

> Знак "Учитель" назначается, как только рейтинг ответа достигает
>   единицы.  Причём перед этим может быть любое количество голосов "за" и
>   "против" в любом порядке.

Тестовое сообщение уже удалено. Тестовый пользователь будет удалён завтра, если к нему не окажется новых вопросов.

---

**Хочу провести эксперимент**

Перевод вроде бы пустяковый, но его точность зависит от того, в какой именно момент присуждается знак `Учитель`:

1. первый голос за ответ должен быть положительным;
2. первые голоса могут быть отрицательными, нужен первый положительный голос;
3. первые голоса могут быть отрицательными, баланс голосов (рейтинг) должен достичь единицы.

Сделал [комнату в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39518/), чтобы обсудить уместный формат эксперимента. Прошу совета, что уместно, что нет и как грамотнее действовать.

---

**Четвёртая попытка**

Нашёл два описания на английском:

1. "[Answer a question with score of 1 or
   more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher)".
2. "[Receive a score of one on an
   answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#68258)".

[Глоссарий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032//1135#1135) переводит `score` как `рейтинг`. Поэтому предлагаю третье толкование: знак `Учитель` даётся в момент, когда рейтинг ответа оказывается единицей. Т.е. при последовательности оценок `против`-`за`-`за` знак будет выдан после второго `за`, а не после первого.

И предлагаю такое описание:

> Получить за ответ рейтинг не менее единицы.

---

**Третья попытка**

В комментариях к ответу Саша Черных доказал мне, что его гипотеза верна.

Я не понимал, почему `Учитель` даётся за рейтинг ответа, но стоит особняком от цепочки `Хороший ответ`, `Отличный ответ` и `Лучший ответ`.

Думаю, смысл знака `Учитель` в том, что человек инициировался в качестве участника, дающего толковые ответы. А знаки `Хороший`, `Отличный`, `Лучший` - уже за качество самих ответов.

С учётом этого еще раз корректирую описание и предлагаю такой вариант:

> Получить первый голос за свой ответ на вопрос.

---

**Вторая попытка**

Проверил описание знаков и делаю вывод, что `Учитель` назначается за ответ на вопрос, если у вопроса минимум 1 балл рейтинга.

За рейтинг у ответов есть [три других знака](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges): `Хороший ответ`, `Отличный ответ` и `Лучший ответ`.

Проверил на пользователе [dio4](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/182615/dio4?tab=answers). Он получил знак `Учитель`, имея два ответа без рейтинга. Зато у одного из вопросов, на которые он отвечал, - рейтинг 1.

Предлагаю такой вариант описания:

> Ответить на вопрос, у которого рейтинг не менее 1 балла.

---

**Первая попытка**

Полагаю, что работает первый вариант и система отмечает знаком факт сам по себе, не учитывая обстоятельства. Например, я получил знак "Критик", когда случайно проголосовал "против". Голос я убрал, а знак "Критика" остался.

Предлагаю вариант описания:

> Получить 1 голос за свой ответ на вопрос.

Comment: dio4 за [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521077/199934) поставили плюс.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Спасибо, был невнимателен. Буду искать дальше. Смущает, что если ваша гипотеза верна,  то `Учитель` должен быть в одной линейке с `Хорошим ответом`...

Comment: @СашаЧерных Нет, всё чётко, вы правы. Я не обратил внимания, что у номинации на знак есть ссылка на ответ, за который она получена.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Видимо, смысл знака в том, что человек инициировался в качестве учителя. А знаки `Хороший`, `Отличный`, `Лучший` - уже зак качество учительства. Сейчас исправлю свой ответ.

Comment: Вероятно, задержка с отображением репутации и здесь случилась. См., например, [тему](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3010/199934).

Comment: @СашаЧерных Обновил свой ответ. Здорово, что благодаря нашему разговору итоговая формулировка стала конкретнее.

Comment: Предлагаю "Получить первый голос за свой ответ <s>на вопрос</s>." - других ответов вроде не бывает.

Comment: @Qwertiy Согласен, так лучше. Добавите ответ со своим вариантом?

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, добавил

Comment: @СашаЧерных Подходит ли моё толкование знака `Учитель` как объяснение обстоятельств, при которых его дают?

Comment: Не знаю, поскольку не уверен, какой из моих двух вариантов верный. Вижу 4 выхода: **[1]** тщательнее погуглить, // **[2]** дождаться здесь разъяснений, // **[3]** спросить на глобальной Мете, // **[4]** потестировать самим: создать только для этого случая виртуала с нулём репутации → задать на основном сайте тестовый вопрос → дать тестовый ответ → заминусовать ответ, а затем пусть кто-нибудь поставит ответу плюс. От того, получит ли виртуал значок, и будет зависеть корректное описание. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных предлагаю четвёртый вариант доя верности и третий - для расширения кругозора :) отвечать можно на уже существующий вопрос кого-то из своих.

Comment: Только 4-й вариант, полагаю, можно воспроизводить только с одобрения модераторов.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Сделал [комнату в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39518/), чтобы обсудить уместный формат эксперимента.

Comment: Отличная инициатива!

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант (с учётом уточнений о получении знака):

> Дать ответ с положительным рейтингом

Предыдущая версия:

> Получить первый голос за свой ответ

Comment: Добавьте точку для полноты ответа :)

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, Qwertiy, я бы всё же разобрался, при каких именно обстоятельствах юзер получает значок, почему и не предложил своих вариантов.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, я посмотрел вопросы, за которые получил этот знак на других сайтах сети - похоже, что ты прав. [Пример](//stackoverflow.com/a/31243678/4928642).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, тоже обновил ответ.

Comment: @Qwertiy На мой вкус, с таким описанием нужно сообразить, что "положительный" - это не просто "неотрицательный", а ещё и "не ноль". Возникает повод для сомнений, правильно ли понял, что имеется в виду. Мне кажется, описание должно снимать любые сомнения и не заставлять шевелить мозгами :)

Comment: Напишите "за первый оцененный ответ" и успокойтесь.  По большому счету  все эти побрякушки настоящих программистов  волновать не должны.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, положительный - это не 0 - это же очевидно...

Comment: @avp Интересна не "побрякушка", а механика, по которой её настроили. Разработать гипотезы, продумать тесты, докопаться до истины и чётко сформулировать результат - имхо классный повод поволноваться.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, расследование ради расследования... Может проще спросить у админов доступ к исходникам?