# Два разных знака переведены как «Наставник»

Tags: предложение, локализация, знаки

Случайно заметил, что у нас [два знака «Наставник»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

1. [Бронзовый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1/teacher) (в оригинале «Teacher»), с описанием «Ответить на вопрос с рейтингом минимум 1 балл.».
2. [Серебрянный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/91/refiner) (в оригинале «Refiner»), с описанием «Отредактировать 50 вопросов и ответить на них (оба действия в течение 12 часов, рейтинг за ответы > 0).».

Это не то чтобы совсем плохо, но по-моему будет лучше их обозвать как-нибудь по-разному во избежание путаницы.

Comment: Teacher раньше и был учителем: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3012/Описание-знака-Учитель Опять локализаторский произвол...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откатил ["Teacher"](https://ru.traducir.win/string/5360) обратно на "Учитель". По традусёру концов пока (а может и вообще) не найти. В транзифексе же только дату видно, когда произошел перевод:

> [image: tansifex]