# Кто имеет право принимать переводы на ru.traducir.win?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, traducir

Кто имеет право принимать переводы на https://ru.traducir.win? Только модераторы или ещё кто-то?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Полный список](https://ru.traducir.win/users) на данный момент (участники с ролью Reviewer):

- g3rv4 ♦.
- Aer.
- Nicolas Chabanovsky ♦.
- Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica ♦.
- αλεχολυτ.
- JNat ♦.
- Qwertiy ♦.
- PashaPash ♦.

Comment: PashаPash вроде ушел из модераторов? И как участники без ромбов заслужили?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica Aer - модератор на РЯ. αλεχολυτ изначально больше всех занимался локализацией ruSO.

Comment: Точки после ромбов - брррррр))

Comment: А что за народ с ромбиками, кстати? Они чьи модераторы?

Comment: @Qwertiy, JNat, Николай и g3rv4  - сотрудники компании.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, ну с Николасом ясно. А других сотрудников у нас вроде больше было? И они ж русский не знают?

Comment: @Qwertiy я так понимаю, в этом списке лишь те, кто пользовались сайтом. AK там вон тоже нет, т.к. он не занимается переводом (не логинился на сайте). g3rv4 - это создатель Традусёра.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica, да, наверное логично. Я тоже не занимаюсь, но я логинился.