# Отсутствие перевода комментария к опции "Выглядит нормально" в очереди проверок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Вероятно, опять на enSO изменили строку, и перевод слетел.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. А можно каким-то образом получать доступ к переводам этих строк и переводить их самостоятельно, чтобы не создавать каждый раз однотипный пост на Мете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16658

Будет доступно в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.6.28.39592

Перевод применён:

> [image: Перевод применён]

---

Предлагать переводы можете самостоятельно на https://ru.traducir.win/. Но для его утверждения нужно [участие редактора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10113/176217).

Comment: А как туда добавлять? Там какой-то ключ строк надо знать.  И какой-то "Source Regex". Как туда предлагать переводы?

Comment: @МаксимФисман [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1137/176217) описано.