# Следует ли создавать вопрос на Мете о мелких грамматических ошибках в переводе сайта?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, локализация

#### Постановка вопроса

Стоит ли создавать отдельные вопросы на Мете о незначительных грамматических, пунктуационных, орфографических неточностях в переводе ruStackOverflow на русский язык?

#### Аргументы

**За:**

- Русская грамматика сложнее английской, поэтому в переводе появляются ошибки, которых в оригинале не было и/или не могло быть ввиду отличий в языках.
- Ошибки на сайте (в документации и руководстве), к тому же на довольно крупном, на мой взгляд, недопустимы.

**Против:**

- Возможно, не нужно дергать модераторов сайта (или кто там еще может подправлять переводы) ради единственной запятой или пробела.
- На Мете есть более важные темы для обсуждения.
- Согласно руководству сайта: [Незначительные правки не приветствуются.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), **НО** это относится только к вопросам и ответам (проще говоря, постам), а не локализации сайта.

### Собственно, примеры

Первый пример, который смог найти, - это причина закрытия вопроса **"Явно не по теме"**, описания которой выглядит так:

```
Сайт «Stack Overflow на русском» не подходящее место для вопроса.
```

- Здесь перед "не" должно быть тире, так как подлежащее `Сайт` и сказуемое `Место` выражены одной частью речи, существительным.
- "Неподходящее" пишется слитно, так как не имеет зависимых слов, и можно подобрать синоним без "не".

Второй пример: второй пункт в теме "Кратко опишите вашу конкретную проблему в заголовке" на странице "Как задать хороший вопрос?":

```
Помните, эту часть вашего вопроса увидят в первую очередь — она должна произвести хорошее впечатление.
```

- Здесь после "Помните" лучше поставить двоеточие, чем запятую, так как это сложное бессоюзное предложение. Его вторая часть раскрывает первую. Обсуждалось нашими коллегами на [rus.StackExchange](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416194/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82)

### Заключение

Разумеется, эти примеры - просто примеры. Я не утверждаю, что их срочно нужно исправлять, однако таких ошибок у нас я заметил уже несколько. Стоит ли развивать эту тему или лучше оставить все как есть с предлогом: "Итак понятно"?

> P.S. В английском после слова [remember стоит запятая](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), причем она там и [должна стоять](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253168/comma-or-colon-after-a-word-like-remember-followed-by-a-sentence-addressed-dir). Формулировка же первой проблемы в оригинале совершенно другая: `This question has nothing to do with programming.`, поэтому не влечет никаких ошибок.

Comment: Следует.⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 7):

Иногда следует, иногда нет.

- В случае явной опечатки или ошибки (грубо говоря, когда достаточно словаря или справочника по языку, чтобы доказать наличие проблемы), вы можете сразу [предложить перевод через Traducir](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/). Если предложение правильно, его одобрят без обсуждения на мете. Хотя если вы не уверены, можно и создать тему, это не запрещено, какой бы незначительной не была ошибка.
- Когда проблема требует обсуждения, потому что существует несколько вариантов определенного написания, и разные группы людей склоняются к разным, нужно создавать вопрос на мете. Так было, например, с выбором между "е" и "ё".
- Если проблема не решаема в рамках русскоязычного сообщества, например, строка собирается из кусков и ее невозможно перевести в соответствии с нормами русского языка, нужно создавать тему не у нас, а на [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что при неочевидных/сложных (даже для носителей языка) ошибках, при создании запроса на исправление стоит предоставить ссылки на какие-либо справочки по языку или предварительно задать вопрос (и получить ответ) на сайте ["Русский язык"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/), тем более, что в большинстве случаев используются общие переводы для rusSE и ruSO.