# Ссылка в баннере принятия файлов cookie не выглядит ссылкой

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, traducir, transifex

В баннере о принятии файлов cookie не разворачивается ссылка:

> [image: Принять cookie]

На других (в том числе неанглоязычных) сайтах сети ссылка выглядит ссылкой.

> [image: Португальский баннер]

Если посмотреть исходный код страницы, то можно увидеть пробел между текстом в квадратных скобках и круглых:

> `... с нашей [Политикой в отношении файлов cookie] (https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy).`

Этот пробел действительно был какое-то время в [переводе на Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16322), но несколько дней назад это было исправлено. Более того, если посмотреть [историю переводов в Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/320139899?q=key%3A4ecdf83027737dbe3ded9ce04bdb3282), то можно заметить какое-то странное передёргивание этого пробела от пользователей traducir.win и stackoverflow:

> [image: Передёргивание пробела]

traducir.win - это пользователь-посредник для обновления переводов через [ru.traducir.win](https://ru.traducir.win), но какую функцию выполняет пользователь stackoverflow в данном случае? Описание достаточно размыто:

> [image: stackoverflow.transifex]

Почему последний перевод, который должен быть действующим, фактически не применился?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm bringing here [my answer from meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368495/238921). Translated using DeepL (feel free to improve it)

Пользователь `stackoverflow` - это то, что мы (Stack Overflow) используем для отправки новых строк в transifex. Еще одна вещь, для которой мы его используем, это управление "переопределениями".

Эти переопределения устанавливаются нами. Иногда эти переопределения были введены туда, потому что человек, работавший над функцией, не знал о Traducir. Но их можно использовать и для того, чтобы сообщество не могло предоставить перевод для строки.

Прямо сейчас `stackoverflow` и `traducir.win` участвуют в гонке за победу своей версии (но... `stackoverflow` всегда побеждает, несмотря на TLD Traducir).

Я подтвердил внутри компании, что мы хотим сами управлять cookie / юридическими вопросами, поэтому эти строки должны быть переведены нами (и значения traducir не будут влиять на то, что отображается на сайте).

Я проверяю, можем ли мы использовать предоставленный сообществом перевод для этой строки.

и я только что понял, что проблема в пробеле... Я подправил это в базе данных, чтобы stackoverflow не разбивал ссылку каждый раз.