# Как следует переводить термин "DMCA Takedowns"?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация, справка, термины

Термин встречается в англоязычной справке, в контексте [Закона об авторском праве в цифровую эпоху (DMCA)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act):

- [What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown)

В справке также встречается термин "DMCA Notice", по контексту означающий то же самое, что и "DMCA Takedown". Возможно, нам следует перевести оба эти термина просто как "Уведомление DMCA":

> Stack Exchange needs to abide by lawful, non-spurious, and validly
> signed takedown requests. If your content has been removed with a DMCA
> Notice, we have received such a notice and have processed it
> accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Принятый перевод:

> Уведомление о нарушении DMCA

Отклонённые варианты:

- DMCA Notice / DMCA takedown notice
- Уведомление DMCA
- Запрос на удаление в соответствии с DMCA
- Нарушение DCMA

Answer (score 0):

В ряде случаев лучше не переизобретать велосипед и смотреть как оно уже переведено. Например на [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/p/ru-ru/legal/dmca-guidelines/), где стримеры больше всего страдают от DMCA.

DMCA Notice / DMCA Takedown notice — уведомление о предполагаемом нарушении авторских прав

Takedown notice можно также дополнительно перевести как "требование о снятии" (контента публикации и т.д.), но уже сложилась практика дословно не переводить. Сравните с [английской версией публикации на Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/p/en/legal/dmca-guidelines/), там takedown тоже фигурирует, но не переводится дословно.

Ну и я бы не переводил DMCA никак. Расшифровывается аббревиатура как Digital Millennium Copyright Act и зная что это, можно хотя бы в оригинале почитать что это за закон, чем какие-то абстрактные авторские права, какой страны?

Поэтому я бы предложил:

> DMCA Notice / DMCA takedown notice

#### Уведомление о предполагаемом нарушении DMCA (авторских прав)

Ключевое слово "предполагаемое" очень хорошо ложится в контекст, т.к. если есть доказанное нарушение, то это будет уже не **notice**.

Answer (score -2):

*Takedown* может буквально переводиться как "нарушение авторских прав". В [английской версии статьи из Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act#Abuse_of_takedown_notice) также не раз упоминается термин *takedown* и он как раз в данном случае он подразумевает под собой нарушение авторских прав, так что я предлагаю перевод:

> Нарушение DCMA

(Или же *Нарушения* т.к. takedowns во мн. числе)

P.S. "Нарушение авторских прав DCMA" будет звучать нелепо т.к. сам по себе термин DCMA уже имеет упоминание об авторском праве, поэтому такой вариант не предлагаю.

А

> Уведомление о нарушении DMCA

Переводится скорее как:

> DCMA takedown notice

Comment: "DMCA Takedown requests are how copyright holders inform us of its existence" — как бы вы это перевели?

Comment: @nomnoms12 вот так: "Запросы на нарушение DCMA это то, как правообладатели информируют нас о его (или "об их" если имеются ввиду правообладатели) существовании".

Comment: "Запрос на нарушение DCMA" звучит так, как будто я спрашиваю разрешение нарушить закон :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 справедливо. Но не стоит придерживаться одного перевода предложенного мной, *requests* имеет множество переводов, один из них *заявление*, а там уже можно и его синонимы попытаться использовать, если они подойдут лучше.